# Sending using Email::Simple with To/From in body text instead of headers

Tags: perl, email

Currently we are using a print to send an html mail via a sendmail pipe, which works fine.

```
$fh->open( q{|sendmail -f<fromaddress> .......} );
```

This comes from a template which contains text like...

```
From: <Fromaddress>
Reply-to: <replyaddress>
Subject: etc
Mine-Version: 1.o
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html...
<html...
rest of body
```

I am now trying to use Email::Simple with the same text

```
my $email = Email::simple->create(
    header => $header,
    body => $body
);

sendmail( $email, { transport => $transport });
```

My headers are like

```
[ To => <toaddress>, From => <fromaddress>, 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' ]
```

This all sends fine, except it includes also the 'From:.. To:: Subject..' as part of the html to be displayed also, whereas sendmail consumes this to be used.

I could use regex to strip out the header content that's included in the text (as it's already generated, but that feels risk prone and clunky), but I'm wondering, is there an Email::Simple way of discarding that, or using only the html instead of the From/To/Subject specific headers provided to Email::Simple ?

I have looked [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart) but can't see any reference to that.

Comment: Why do you have that "header" stuff in the email body at all? This makes no sense. Remove it if you're not piping to `sendmail`.

Comment: This is due to some old legacy code, and another system uses that, so I'm trying to find a solution where not too many files need to be amended (it may well be as part of this change, that later gets removed anyway, but it's an intermediate step).

Comment: Email::Simple does not know about your custom way of structuring the email body. I can only recommend to strip your custom way if you cannot restructure your templates: `$body =~ s!\A.*?\r\n\r\n!!s;`

Answer (score 2):

I assume your `$body` variable contains the text from one of your template files. And as those templates contain the headers, they will end up duplicated in the body of your email messages.

The best approach is to edit your templates to remove the header sections.

But if you can't do that for some reason, you can pre-process `$body` before passing it to the `create()` method. Something like this, perhaps:

```
(undef, $body) = split /\n\n/, $body, 2;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `split(/\r\n\r\n/, ....)`? Unless of course this is `$body` before handing it off to Email::Simple.

Comment: ... also, if `$body` contains one more empty line, this will mutilate `$body`. Using the three argument version of `split` should work: `(undef, $body) = split /\n\n/, $body, 2;`

Comment: @Corion: Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: @StefanBecker: As I said, "before passing it to the create() method".

Answer (score 2):

Actually the answer is simpler than I thought...

If you just use

```
my $email = Email::Simple->new( $text );
sendmail( $email, { transport => $transport });
```

It will use the headers from the text/body, and not include them in the main body.

If you use

```
my $email = Email::Simple->create( $text );
sendmail( $email, { transport => $transport });
```

It seems to need the separate headers, and sends out the headers in the text as part of the main data/html that's sent out.